# Should input be accepted after confimation (or other actions)

Tags: forms, input, response-time, workflow, actions

I often find myself in the following workflow:

1. Enter user name
2. Enter password
3. Click "OK" (or enter key)
4. Wait for response
5. Discover the checkbox next to OK-button
6. Think: "Bugger!  It would be nice to skip this on login at my next visit..."
7. If slow response: Actually tick the checkbox - knowing it wont matter... (or will it?)

[image]

**Should input (check the checkbox) it be accepted after the "conformation" button is clicked?**

*If so*: How should the the feedback to the user be?  (aka. "We have noticed that you changed your mind")

*If not*:  How could this be prevented.

---

Another example (where input actually *is* accepted):

1. Read an interesting question at UX.SE
2. Upvote it
3. Navigate a away from question (eg. "go home" or "view user)
4. Remember: "Ah.  Would be nice to have a second look this question!"
5. Click the "favorite star".  (And this is actually accepted and remembered.  The same with voting.)

[image]

---

I know that the last example can be interpreted as "another action" (with a faster independent AJAX-call to the server) instead of "changing the input".  But they are IMHO essentially the same.  The star is a checkbox, the "remember me" could just as well be  visualized with a toggle-immage.

In both cases I'm moving away, and in both cases I sincerely remember that I should have done just one more thing before I carried on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a standard practice, user input is not accepted after user submits a page.

In client server applications, this is achieved by disabling the form after user submit.

In web applications also, to avoid user input after submitting page, a technique called blocking the UI is followed. After processing is over, UI is unblocked again.

[image]

This might be seen as breaking the user experience in some cases but in my opinion, it avoids confusion and brings in data integrity for critical applications.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  "It's just not possible" is probably the best practice to use...  The "Forgot to check `Stay signed in´"-issue _is_ real and relevant, but should be solved by a redesign of the form, so that the options is noticed _before_ " signing in.

Answer (score 3):

Nice question, but I think they actually are completely different cases.

While the state of the checkbox may be remembered for your next login the value is only valid for this login. When you log out, you should be logged out and this should not affect the remembered value for your next login. As such the checkbox isn't an indication of some permanent state (as the favorite star is), but only of the session you start with the login you just submitted.

If you compared the favorite star with a form of some (permanent) profile information then you would have closer matching cases as they both modify permanent information. But then the comparison is just between automatic and explicit save.